# nvd3.js - display specific color for each bar in multibar vertical chart depending on range of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

As the topic says, I simply want to customize the color of each bar based on the value of the y axis.

The range of value-colors are:

- 0-50: green
- 50-75: yellow
- 75-100: red

I tried to search this topic on Google a lot but could not find any results.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038534/d3-js-changing-the-color-of-the-bar-depending-on-the-value) was the closest to my answer however it's not for nvd3. If in case it is, please do tell me which location I am supposed to add the functions.

My codes are as follow:-

**HTML:-**

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="data2"></nvd3>
```

**JS:-**

```
/* Chart options */
$scope.options = { /* JSON data */

          chart: {
              type: 'multiBarChart',
              height: 250,
              showControls: false,
              margin : {
                  top: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  bottom: 45,
                  left: 45
              },
              clipEdge: true,
              duration: 500,
              stacked: true,
              xAxis: {
                  axisLabel: 'Time (ms)',
                  showMaxMin: false,
                  tickFormat: function(d){
                      return d3.format(',f')(d);
                  }
              },
              yAxis: {
                  axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                  axisLabelDistance: -20,
                  tickFormat: function(d){
                      return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                  }
              }
          },

// title options
title: {
    enable: true,
    text: 'Title for Line Chart'
},

// subtitle options
subtitle: {
    enable: true,
    text: 'Subtitle for simple line chart. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    css: {
        'text-align': 'center',
        'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
    }
},

// caption options
caption: {
    enable: true,
    html: 'Figure 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    css: {
        'text-align': 'justify',
        'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
    }
   }
 };

 /* Chart data */
 $scope.data2 = [{"key":"Thermal","values":[{"x":0,"y":44},{"x":1,"y":24},{"x":2,"y":66},{"x":3,"y":10},{"x":4,"y":33}]}];
```

Comment: Hi guys. Please do help me out as I have tried finding a lot of possible ways but was unable to find any success for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948502/1575353) and the code in responses from [this github issue](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/8), it was found that 
[d3.selectAll()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selectAll) can be utilized in the *callback* option for the chart.

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'multiBarChart',
        //...,
        callback: function(){
            d3.selectAll('rect.nv-bar')
            .style('fill', function(d, i) {
                  if (d.y > 75) {
                    return 'red';
                  }
                  if (d.y > 50) {
                    return 'yellow';
                  }
                  return 'green';
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See a demonstration of the changes applied by running the code in the snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = { /* JSON data */
    chart: {
      type: 'multiBarChart',
      height: 250,
      showControls: false,
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 45,
        left: 45
      },
      clipEdge: true,
      duration: 500,
      stacked: true,
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Time (ms)',
        showMaxMin: false,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format(',f')(d);
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
        axisLabelDistance: -20,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
        }
      },
      callback: function() {
        //console.log('in callback');
        d3.selectAll('rect.nv-bar')
          .style('fill', function(data, index) {
              //console.log('data.y: ',data.y);
            if (data.y > 75) {
              return 'red';
            }
            if (data.y > 50) {
              return 'yellow';
            }
            return 'green';
          });
      }
    },

    // title options
    title: {
      enable: true,
      text: 'Title for Line Chart'
    },

    // subtitle options
    subtitle: {
      enable: true,
      text: 'Subtitle for simple line chart. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
      css: {
        'text-align': 'center',
        'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
      }
    },

    // caption options
    caption: {
      enable: true,
      html: 'Figure 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
      css: {
        'text-align': 'justify',
        'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
      }
    }
  };

  /* Chart data */
  $scope.data2 = [{
    "key": "Thermal",
    "values": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 44
    }, {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 24
    }, {
      "x": 2,
      "y": 66
    }, {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 10
    }, {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 33
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <nvd3 options="options" data="data2"></nvd3>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the kind response and apologies for the delayed response. I believe this is an error on their side but I could be wrong... however when i close my browser developer tools or click that little blue dot at top right, the colors revert back to default.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to change bar colour... i am putting this code because callback didn't work for me ...u need to change the logic to select bar according to your need

```
dispatch: {
        renderEnd: function (e) {
            d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").attr('rx', 4).attr('ry', 4).attr('width', 15).style("fill", function (d, i){
                if (i%4==0)
                {
                  return "#0064A5"
                }   
                else if (i%3==0)
                {
                  return "#2C76B8"
                } 
                else if (i%2==0)
                {
                  return "#004C76"
                }  
                else{
                  return "#004180"

                }     

            }); 



        }
      }
```